# multiple ajax request using $http best practice

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, angularjs

best practice to write multiple $http request? or the best is u put all the query (I'm using php and mysql) into one page?

is it good to write below code twice or more?

```
   $http({
    url: "php/mainLoad.php",
    method: "GET",
    params: {"userId":"1"}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.mydata = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       // $scope.status = status;
       alert(status);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It typically depends on the application and the type of API you are implementing.

Consider functionality A, B, and C.

If A and B are always called as a pair and C is sometimes called with A and B but not always, it might be a good idea to combine A and B into a single call and keep C separate so you don't have any logic duplication. If there is ever a time you might need to call A or B separately, it probably means you should keep all of them as separate services. This goes along with DRY (Don't repeat yourself) methodology.

In general, http requests themselves aren't THAT expensive so keeping your logic clean and testable is normally a better option then creating a custom request for every single action that might take place.

RESTful is an extremely popular type of web service implementation that might be worth checking out and understanding.